# better way of printing the function caller's line number

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I have a function defined as follows:

```
printPrettyJson =
    function (json)
    {
        // logger.log(chalk.magenta(JSON.stringify(json, null, 4)))
        try 
        {
            throw Error("printPrettyJson")
        }
        catch (error) 
        {
            console.log(error.stack)
            console.debug(chalk.magenta(JSON.stringify(json, null, 4)))
        }
    }
```

What I do with this is to simply print out a JSON kind of object (since it'll otherwise show `[Object object]`. However, I was wondering if I do this without throwing a clumsy `Error`. I'm calling it from another file e.g.

File1

```
const printPrettyJson = require("file2)

Line 101: printPrettyJson(json)
```

File2

```
// printPrettyJson's definition in here
```

So how would I output `line 101` from File1 on `printPrettyJson`'s function call?

Comment: Would [`console.trace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/trace) help out?

Comment: @trincot that might actually be good enough. I did that before and it was outputting red text with `[object Object]` and I thought it was throwing an error. But I guess it's actually just printing the stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just output the call stack without raising an error, using [`console.trace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/trace). It is in the [standard](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#trace) specifications for the `console` API.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the line number from the stack trace by creating a new error object, it is not necessary to actually throw an error:

```
printPrettyJson =
    function (json)
    {
        console.log(new Error().stack)
        console.debug(chalk.magenta(JSON.stringify(json, null, 4)))
    }
```